# Let A be a subset of R with more than one element, let a in A. If A-{a} is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness, connectedness, path-connected

Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb R$ with more than one element, let $a$ in $A$. If $A-\{a\}$ is compact, then

1. $A$ is compact
2. Every subset of $A$ must be compact
3. $A$ must be finite set
4. $A$ is disconnected

for any open cover of $A$ is also open cover for $A-\{a\}$, since $A-\{a\}$  is compact implies that it has finite sub cover to cover $A-\{a\}$. with this sub cover union an open set containing $a$ will be the finite sub cover for $A$. Hence $A$ is compact

Given that $A-\{a\}$  is compact, so it is closed, this implies $\{a\}$ is open. But every singleton in $\mathbb{R}$ is closed, so $\{a\}$ is both closed and open. Hence A is disconnected

so option (1) and (4) is right.  what can we say about option (2) and (3)?

Comment: Hint:  Let $B=A-\{a\}$.  Then $A=B\cup \{a\}$

Comment: Surely there are no reasons for 2 and 3 to be true and you can come up with counter examples.  Let A-{a} be ... any compact set ... say [0,1] and so A = [0,1] U {a}.  Surely this has non compact subsets and surely is not finite.

Comment: that $a$ removed from $A$ is not fixed one. $A-\{a\}$  is compact for any $a \in A$, so if i take a element from that closed interval, then the set remains not compact. a contradiction to the hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof that 1) is true is ok.

But if $A=\{a\}$ then $A\setminus \{a\}$ is compact and $A$ is connected. So 4) is false.

Counterexamples to 2) and 3) are given in comments: $A=[0,1]\cup\{3\}$ and $a=3$

Comment: if $a$ is fixed, then  $A=[0,1]\cup\{3\}$ is perfect counterexample for 2) and 3). But, in the question $a$ is arbitrary. so if i remove any element from the closed interval it remains not compact, it is contradiction to the hypothesis.

Comment: yes, i got it. thank you

Comment: It is not stated in the Q that $A$ \ $\{a\}$ is compact for every $a\in A.$ The phrase "let $a\in A$ such that..." means  "There exists $a\in A$ such that..."

Comment: yes... now i understand thank you

Comment: This is incorrect answer. Question says A has more than one element.